# Where do generic "note" objects go?

Tags: prey

Normally when I interact with a sticky note, the game lets me read it just like a book. However, I have found a few notes that, when I interact with them, simply disappear with an animation like they're going into my inventory. However, nothing new shows up in my inventory and no new entry is added to my Notes section of the Data tab.

What's going on here? Is this a bug? Is it just not giving me anything because these sticky notes are duplicates of ones I've already read? Is there some other place in the menu I should be looking to find these?

Comment: If you're talking about the "Not a mimic" notes, they simply disappear. Which notes do you mean exactly?

Comment: @ChrᴉzremembersMonica Maybe those are the ones. I found one on top of a shelving unit in Helen Barker-Combes' office, and one next to the corpse of Rory Manion just outside that office. This is just outside Labs B in Psychotronics.